# How long does radiation contamination take to clean up?

Tags: simcity-2013

Due to poorly educated workers at my nuclear power plant, I was told that a meltdown was imminent at my power plant. Considering how densely packed my city is, I didn't fancy having a meltdown and removed the nuclear power plant in favour of an oil power plant.

However, it seems that some contamination of the area has still occurred. Sims living and working nearby are now getting sick from the contamination. How long does it take for the radiation contamination to completely dissipate?

Here's a screenshot showing the contamination:
[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, does your fire department have a HazMat team?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"you have to wait 20+ years for all the radiation to turn into ground pollution 
(which trees help clean up)"

[Answer by Guillaume Pierre](https://twitter.com/MaxisGuillaume/status/311026083040468992) - The Lead Gameplay Scripter and a Designer

**Update**

"also the lowest radiation area will take about 34 years to go away, with each band of intensity being 2x that"

[Answer by Chris Schmidt](https://twitter.com/maxisbigtuna/status/314840414765080576) - Tuning Designer at Maxis

Comment: 20 years = 240 days...

Answer (score 1):

My water pump was right next to my nuclear power station that went into meltdown, I have the filtration add-on and the ground pollution is very light after a few days of pumping just below the pump station, but heavy everywhere else.

That's right, get your population to drink it!

Comment: Of course that won't help remove the source of the pollution any faster (that is, to remove the radiation).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to decay slowly after a while. My city got hit by a meteor and the radiation level is slowly decreasing.

Comment: Do you know how much it has decreased by over a specific time?

Comment: A very negligible amount - this question is going to be hard to answer definitively for now, I was in a similar situation in that I had a meteor hit my city in Year 1 - by Year 5 the radiation only appeared to have decreased by a tiny amount, I would estimate that the radiation from a nuclear fallout would take 20-30 or even more years to clear itself up.

Comment: @kalina Isn't it like that in the real world aswell? Radiation decays at a real slow pace and there is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: pretty much yes - the point is you're not supposed to be using a nuclear power plant until you have the required education level to operate it safely, the clue is in the tooltip IMO!