# How do I clean up radioactivity/radiation?

Tags: simcity-2013

A small section of my city in the corner has been affected by radiation. All the buildings (including shops and houses) now show signs of radioactivity. When I bulldoze them, the radiation disappears, but when the buildings are rebuilt, they are still affected.

I have an Oil Factory right smack in the middle from where the radioactivity is coming from. But even when I bulldoze the Oil factory, the radiation is still there.

How do I get rid the radioactivity?

Comment: Take a look at http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108074/how-long-does-radiation-contamination-take-to-clean-up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Radioactivity decays over time and turns into ground pollution. There is currently no way to buy yourself radiation cleanup.

Comment: By time you mean 20+ years....